# How to point a DomainName to an Apache Tomcat Server?

Tags: linux, tomcat, domain-name

I have a domain name and I want to point it to a local apache tomcat server that I have installed and started on my machine(static IP)

What kind of configuration I need to do with the DNS(at the website of the domain name company) and tomcat configuration files - I assume!

PS. I am using Tomcat6 on a linux machine with static IP

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If the local apache server has a routable IP address, then just set up the A record on
the domain name DNS server through their web-based management interface.

If the local apache server is on a private IP (i.e. 10.x.x.x, 172.{16-31}.x.x or 192.168.x.x) then you cannot accomplish this without running a local caching DNS server.  Those addresses are non-routable.  If this is the case AND you have configuration access to the firewall/router doing NAT you could configure port forwarding, in which case the DNS entry for the server would point to your firewall's public IP address.